# How can I add jquery plugin to “page-scroll-effects-master” navigation, menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the plugin to have a menu, from which you can insert the page into the hand.

I tried to go through sections using #.

I think jquery's code is well-known, because you can find the code and add the menu.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried

Comment: Here is a plugin link and I need to add the menu from where I can go to other pages. codyhouse.co/gem/page-scroll-effects

Comment: https://codyhouse.co/gem/page-scroll-effects

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

Comment: no bro, i need menu, navbar. Here is a plugin link and I need to add the menu from where I can go to other pages. https://codyhouse.co/gem/page-scroll-effects